# Flutter invalid constant value (on excercise from flutter apprentice book)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

When creating this stateless widget I try to assign a TextDecoration value to a widget attribute based on the value of a boolean attribute from the object being passed to it on creation.

`textDecoration = item.isComplete ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none,`

On this row it marks `item.isComplete` as an error, saying **invalid constant value**.
Is it because `isComplete` in the class is defined with the `late` keyword and therefore it could be null? I checked all the possible causes for which the invalid constant value error migh arise and I still haven't made any sort of dent into it.

The widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../models/grocery_item.dart';

class GroceryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryItem item;
  final Function(bool?)? onComplete;
  final TextDecoration textDecoration;

  const GroceryTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
    this.onComplete,
  })  : textDecoration = item.isComplete // Error here
            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
            : TextDecoration.none,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

The class:

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

enum Importance { low, medium, high }

class GroceryItem {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final Importance importance;
  final Color color;
  final int quantity;
  final DateTime date;
  late bool isComplete;

  GroceryItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.importance,
    required this.color,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.date,
    this.isComplete = false,
  });

  GroceryItem copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? name,
    Importance? importance,
    Color? color,
    int? quantity,
    DateTime? date,
    bool? isComplete,
  }) {
    return GroceryItem(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        name: name ?? this.name,
        importance: importance ?? this.importance,
        color: color ?? this.color,
        quantity: quantity ?? this.quantity,
        date: date ?? this.date,
        isComplete: isComplete ?? this.isComplete);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `const` keyword before `GroceryTile` contructor.

Comment: d'oh! my god how did i miss that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The const constructor cannot have a body and if you want to initialize some value in the constructor body you need to remove the `const` keyword

```dart
//...
  GroceryTile({ // <- Remove `const`here
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
    this.onComplete,
  })  : textDecoration = item.isComplete
            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
            : TextDecoration.none,
        super(key: key);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class GroceryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryItem item;
  final Function(bool?)? onComplete;
  final TextDecoration textDecoration;

  GroceryTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
    this.onComplete,
  })  : textDecoration = item.isComplete
            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
            : TextDecoration.none,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```